# Docker-Compose Args (Variable Expansion) in Multi-stage Builds

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to use docker-compose `ARG`s in multi-stage build context. My dockerfile looks like this:

```
ARG PHP_VERSION

FROM php:${PHP_VERSION}

ARG COMPOSER_VERSION

COPY --from=composer:${COMPOSER_VERSION} /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
```

The `PHP_VERSION` argument is working just fine. However, the `COMPOSER_VERSION` in the fourth line results in the following error:

`ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build: invalid from flag value composer:${COMPOSER_VERSION}: invalid reference format`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variable expansion is not supported in `COPY --from`. See [this issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34482) for more details. You can modify your Dockerfile to implement this by defining a stage that you late copy from:

```
ARG PHP_VERSION
ARG COMPOSER_VERSION

FROM composer:${COMPOSER_VERSION} as composer
FROM php:${PHP_VERSION}

COPY --from=composer /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
```